# Simple split code

Tags: assembly, x86

I have a split a code and am trying to understand each part of it. I have learnt very well java, c++ and many languages, but assembly was difficult for me, so I came here.

I think that I know it, but I am not sure(it passed a long time). I checked on the internet, but I can't find anything. I wrote some things from code I had, because I wanted to test my knowledge, so, at this split code I have some comments. Please let me know if I am right or wrong. Please tell me where I'm wrong.

The program I use generally is emu8086. I don't know if this is playing an important role. The code may not be well-formatted, because it is only partial code.

1) `MOV DS,AX`  --->   mean that AX will take the DS.The "variable" lets say

2) `LEA DX,MESSAGE` ---> LEA means load to DX

3) `MOV AH,9` ---->Give(i am not sure if means move) the 9 to AH

4) `INT 21H` --->stops

5) `MOV AL, N`
   Move N to AL
      `MUL AL`    --->multiple the AL that means N and N.More specific N*N

6) `MOV SI, AX`  --->AX goes to SI (i hope with this to remember it good).That means N*N goes to SI?

```
`MOV BL, 2`    --->Give 2 to BL 
`MOV AL, N`    --->Take N and give it to AL 
`MUL BL`        --->BL * AL?if i am not doing wrong that it is 2* N
```

7) `SUB SI,AX`  ---> AX ( N*N) -SI(2*N) 
`INC SI`            ---> ?appear the sub?

8) `MOV AX,SI`   --->SI goes to AX.2*N goes to AX.Now AX is 2*N 
    `MOV CL,10`  --->10 goes to CL 
    `DIV CL`         -->2*N / 10 ?

9)`MOV CL,AH` --> AH  "variable" goes to  CL 
`MOV DL,AL`    -->AL    "variable" goes to DL 
`ADD DL,48`     -->DL will be AL +48

Comment: http://www.posix.nl/linuxassembly/nasmdochtml/nasmdoca.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Means: move (or copy/load) `AX` to `DS` (so the opposite you said)
2. Means: load `MESSAGE`'s address into `DX`
3. Means what you said. `MOV` is for move
4. Calls a subroutine. In this case it will print `MESSAGE` on screen [see here for details](http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html#ah09)
5. Right
6. Right
7. Right. `INC SI` means: increase `SI` by 1.
8. `SI` goeas into `AX` but the value is N*N - 2*N + 1 (If I'm following calculations properly). Also `DIV` works as you think, but remember about missing part of calculations ;)
9. Right